# HSQLDB independent for unit testing

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, junit, hsqldb

I use HSQLDB for JUnit unit testing a set of **hibernate** classes and queries. In each test's `setUp()` call I initialize an in-memory hsql database (through hibernate) using the name of the test class and test case to compose the connection string for the in-memory db instance. But in my second test, the ID sequence seems to continue from the first test. I want my tests to be absolutely independent obviously so this surprises me. I'm using `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` for my id's. My intended development and production database is mysql or postgresql but that shouldn't matter here.

**Update**
I tried a smaller test case, and it turns out that I was wrong. I did create more entities in the secodn test, which resulted in a different id. My bad entirely!

Comment: That's unexpected behavior. Can you post the code from `setUp()` that you are using to initialize the database connection?

Comment: I tried a smaller test case, and it turns out that I was wrong. I did create more entities in the secodn test, which resulted in a different id. My bad entirely!

Comment: Actually, your second test should not depend on the actual value of generated ID. The test should not make any implicit assumptions about its environment.

Comment: I know, I wasn't particularly asserting the generated id, I was investigating an issue as if that id were a symptom.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the HSQLDB Memory database will be dropped only after the application terminate.

You could bengi a transaction before each test class and rollback it when the test class finished.